# ERC20 pricing with parameters

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, mobile-wallet

I have created an ERC-20 token called  FBC in Ethereum however I am supposed to trigger the price of the FBC with my parameter service produced from the broadge soccer data. For instance, when Fenerbahçe wins a match the price of the FBC should be increased.

However, as I have researched over the web I couldn't find any instance or hint for this case and what I am asking you

Am I using the right type of token?

Should I create another instance of value in my smart-contract to assign as the FBC or should I change the pattern of the token?

Comment: What do you mean with "price"? Do you mean compared to some fiat?

Comment: Where is your token traded? The token price is set by the trading venue.

Comment: For instance I want my token start from the price of 0.01 eth than to increase according to my trigger mechanism. What type of token or asset should I create? Please note that this token/asset should be spent in the dedicated places as coins.